# The server returned unexpected error - Firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-remote-config

I Have connected my app with database and remote config, it was working fine, but i had to change my gmail account linked with the firebase

So i updated the google json file , with the new json i got from dif. gmail account, Now with the same code, with the same database format i am not able to view it.

It says, Fetch problem - the server returned unexpected error

I Have not make changes with the code, I have just change the content of json file (Google services) and the account linked with firebase.

How to solve this issue?

Here are the logs:

```
2019-08-20 15:42:30.756 1797-1826/com.appnotification.notificationhistorylog E/FirebaseRemoteConfig: Fetch failed!
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigServerException: Fetch failed: The server returned an unexpected error.
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzes.zzc(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzes.zzb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzes.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.then(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
2019-08-20 15:42:30.757 1797-1797/com.appnotification.notificationhistorylog E/TaskError: firebaseremote
2019-08-20 15:42:30.757 1797-1797/com.appnotification.notificationhistorylog E/TaskError: taskexcep :Fetch failed: The server returned an unexpected error.com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigServerException: Fetch failed: The server returned an unexpected error.com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@dd0395b
```

And here is my `RemoteConfig` code:

```
firebaseRemoteConfigprice.fetch(0).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
              Log.e("TaskError", "info" + firebaseRemoteConfigprice.getInfo().getLastFetchStatus());
              Log.e("TaskError", "firebaseremote" + firebaseRemoteConfigprice.getString("btn_text"));

              if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                 firebaseRemoteConfigprice.activateFetched();
                 /*txt600.setText(firebaseRemoteConfigprice.getString("txt600"));
                 txt1500.setText(firebaseRemoteConfigprice.getString("txt1500"));

                 txt3200.setText(firebaseRemoteConfigprice.getString("txt3200"));
                 txt5000.setText(firebaseRemoteConfigprice.getString("txt5000")); */

                 whatnew =(firebaseRemoteConfigprice.getString("whatsnew"));
                            versionfirebase=(firebaseRemoteConfigprice.getString("version"));


                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NoticeActivity.this);


                 builder.setTitle("What's New ");

                 builder.setMessage(whatnew+"\n\nLatest Version"+versionfirebase);
                            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.notificationlogo);

                 builder.setPositiveButton("GOT IT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                           dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                 });

                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();


                            Log.e("TaskError","firebaseremote"+ firebaseRemoteConfigprice.getString("btn_text"));


                                   /* Picasso.get().load(firebaseRemoteConfigprice.getString("image_link"))
                                            .into(img);*/
                        } else {


                            String exp = (""+task.getException().getMessage());
                            if (exp.equals("null")){

                                whatnew=("Server Not Responding ");

                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NoticeActivity.this);


                                builder.setTitle("What's New ");

                                builder.setMessage(whatnew);
                                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.notificationlogo);

                                builder.setPositiveButton("GOT IT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });

                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();


                                // Toast.makeText(PriceListActivity.this, "Taking Longer Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                               /* txt600.setText("600 Credit (70% Off)");
                                txt1500.setText("1500 Credit(50% Off)");
                                txt3200.setText("3200 Credit(50% Off)");
                                txt5000.setText("5000 Credits(70% Off)");*/



/*

                                 txt600.setText(credit600+"/600 Credits");
                                 txt1500.setText(credit1500+"/1500 Credits");
                                 txt3200.setText(credit3200+"/3200 Credits");
                                 txt5000.setText(credit5000+"/5000 Credits");
*/


                            }
                            else {
                                Log.e("TaskError","taskexcep :"+ task.getException().getMessage()+task.getException()+task);
                                Toast.makeText(NoticeActivity.this, "" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: did you check if the database has new security rules?

Comment: what ? I am running the real time database in test mode

Comment: post your code and your logs

Comment: done, added the logs and code

Comment: is remoteconfig api enabled in your google console?

Comment: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1010

Comment: if i enable the api for remote conf then also database is also not fetching the data

Comment: what's the error on the db part?

Comment: no data is shown, just the progress bar is moving

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198171/discussion-between-kushan-and-harshil-patel).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by changing version of google play service classpath

from

```js
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

To

```js
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```